# How can I send a ngRessource request again in error interceptor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope

I need to authenticate on a custom oauth2 API. So I use the angular module [angular-oauth2](https://github.com/oauthjs/angular-oauth2). The authentication works. If a request fails cause the AccessToken isn't valid anymore, I need to refresh the accessToken with the refreshToken. The refreshment works, but after that I have to send the request that failed before again. Hope someone have an idea how to send that request again.

```
.controller('StartCtrl', function($scope, $sampleapi) {
  $scope.load = function(){
    $sampleapi.account.getData({}, function(result){
        $scope.data = result;
    });
  };
  $scope.$on("$ionicView.enter", $scope.load());
});
```

That's the controller that triggers the request.

```
.factory('$sampleapi', function($resource, baseUrl){
  return {
    account: $resource(baseUrl, {}, {
      getData: {
        method: 'GET',
        url: baseUrl + '/endpoint',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 30000
      }
    })
  }
})
```

The factory that makes all requests.

```
$rootScope.$on('oauth:error', function(event, rejection){
  if(rejection.data.error === 'invalid_grant' && rejection.data.error_description === 'Invalid username and password combination') {
    //login failed
  }
  else if(rejection.data.error === 'invalid_grant' && rejection.data.error_description === 'The access token provided has expired.') {
    //request new accessToken with refreshToken
    OAuth.getRefreshToken().then(function(){
      //accessToken refreshed -> send failed request again HOW??
    }); 
  }
  else if(rejection.data.error === 'invalid_grant' && rejection.data.error_description === 'Refresh token has expired'){
    //refreshToken not valid anymore -> logout
  }
  else {
    //some other error
  }
});
```

The error interceptor that catches any failed requests.

The response from the repeated request should be avaible in the StartCtrl scope.

Comment: Interceptors should be added to the `$httpProvider.interceptors` array. See [AngularJS $http Service API Reference -- interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors).

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> ### Interceptors
>
> For purposes of global error handling, **authentication**, or any kind of synchronous or asynchronous pre-processing of request or postprocessing of responses, it is desirable to be able to intercept requests before they are handed to the server and responses before they are handed over to the application code that initiated these requests.
>
> The interceptors are service factories that are registered with the `$httpProvider` by adding them to the `$httpProvider.interceptors` array. The factory is called and injected with dependencies (if specified) and returns the interceptor.

-- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference -- interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)